# How to find unique records from multiple columns of a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a table which has 45 columns. Column `SrNo` has a `primary key`. It has millions of records. It contains so many duplicates. I actually want to find unique values and want to insert them into another table. Columns `First-Middle-Last Name`, `Emails`(Office,Personal),`MobileNumbers` contain so many duplicates. I am trying to find unique values using below query but it still showing result with duplicates. Can anyone help me where am I mistaking?

```
SELECT ft.first_name
     , ft.middle_name
     , ft.last_name
     , ft.designation
     , ft.company_name
     , ft.email_office
     , ft.email_personal1
     , ft.email_personal2
     , ft.personal_mobile1
     , ft.personal_mobile2                                                                        
  FROM mytable ft    
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT First_Name
            , Middle_Name
            , Last_Name
            , designation
            , Company_Name
            , Email_Office
            , Email_Personal1
            , Email_Personal2
            , Personal_Mobile1
            , Personal_Mobile2
            , COUNT(*)
         FROM mytable
        GROUP 
           BY First_Name
            , Middle_Name
            , Last_Name
            , designation
            , Company_Name
            , Email_Office
            , Email_Personal1
            , Email_Personal2
            , Personal_Mobile1
            , Personal_Mobile2
       HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     ) temp
    ON temp.first_name = ft.First_Name 
   AND temp.middle_name = ft.Middle_Name 
   AND temp.last_name = ft.Last_Name 
   AND temp.designation = ft.Designation 
   AND temp.company_name = ft.Company_Name 
   AND temp.email_office = ft.Email_Office 
   AND temp.email_personal1 = ft.Email_Personal1 
   AND temp.email_personal2 = ft.Email_Personal2 
   AND temp.personal_mobile1 = ft.Personal_Mobile1 
   AND temp.personal_mobile2 = ft.Personal_Mobile2
 WHERE srno <= 1000;
```

Its taking so much time to execute a query on fulldata, as it has millions. Thats why I've to put `where` condition to show records upto 1000.

Its showing duplicates in `Emails`,3 columns of `Names` too. Can anyone help me whats wrong in this query? Or Am I making it more complicate this way?

Also how to get those records whose `count(*) > 1`, how do I take only one record of them while ignoring its other duplicates?

Below is my sample table representation.

```
+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Designation       | CompanyName | Email(o)       | Email(P1)       | Email(P2)           | Mobile(pl) | Mobile(p2) | 
+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| Anil      |            |          | Personnel Manager | ABC         | anilgabc.com   | anilggmail.com  |                     | 9898989898 |        | 
| Anil      | D          | Gupta    | Personnel Manager | ABC         | anilggmail.com |         |             |        |        | 
| Anil      | D          |          |                   | ABC         | anilg@abc.com  |         |             |        |        | 
| Anil      |            | Gupta    | Personnel Manager |             |                |                 | anilgreditfmail.com | 9898989898 |        | 
| Anil      |            | Gupta    |                   | ABC         |                |                 |                     | 9898989898 |        | 
| Anil      | D          | Gupta    | Personnel Manager | ABC         | anilgabc.com   | anilg@gmail.com | anilgrediffmail.com | 9898989898 |        | 
+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

And here's the desired result...

Comment: which field you want unique first name or middle name or last name or email.  Or Combination of First + last + Middlle + email unique

Comment: I want whole unique record (a row) means combination of all these fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct for the table that has multiple the same records first then join the other table you need: like this,,

```
     select  distinct    ft.first_name,ft.middle_name,ft.last_name,ft.designation,ft.company_name,ft.emai  l_office,ft.email_personal1, ft.email_personal2,  ft.personal_mobile1,     ft.personal_mobile2                                                                        
      from mytable ft    and so on
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried using distinct but that didn't work. It was still showing duplicate records. But at that time, I didn't join the other table. Let me try this way. Get back to you in few minutes. Also one more thing, why its taking too much time to execute only 1000 records? I have total 1100000 records.

Comment: Execute first the table that has multiple duplicate records and use distinct in to it. Query first the specific column that has multiple record with primary key and use distinct then join the whole with same table and you can get the best result im sure.

Comment: Trying. In my subquery, "having count(*)=1" is correct? How will I get only one record from all those records whose count(*)>1 ?? Should I write "having count(*)>=1" ??

Comment: just need to be more clearer.. is just a duplicate records or duplicate just like only email but not the same name? Im just imagining your table coz i dont have it.

Comment: I've attached one image in my question. It shows sample data table. Check it out.

Comment: Try to look at that image above.

Comment: My internet connection drops after every few minutes. just checked your messages. My attached image is as link "Sample Table" at the end of my question. Yes seen your images, I want like that. using only distinct in a query, doesn't show accurate result. It still shows duplicate records.While I use it with inner join, its taking more than 15 minutes for  execution of 1000 records